# Weird Jquery error on display

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

my controller code is

```
public function actionStl_getchildren()
    {

        $sql    = "SELECT parent.id AS account, ifnull( ABS( SUM(gle.debit)-SUM(gle.credit) ), 0 ) AS balance,
            parent.group_or_ledger, parent.lft 
            FROM tabAccount AS parent, tabAccount AS node
            LEFT JOIN `tabGLEntry` gle ON ( gle.account = node.id )
            WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) and parent.parent_account='{$_POST['parent']}' 
            AND parent.is_deleted=0
            GROUP BY parent.id
            ORDER BY parent.id";
        $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $sql )->queryAll();

        foreach ( $result as $id => $r )
        {
            $result[ $id ][ 'balance' ] =  $r[ 'balance' ];
        }

        echo json_encode( [ 'accounts' => $result ] );
    }
```

my view (only relevant code)

```
function loadChildren($this)
        {
            var tl = $this;
            tl.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-folder');
            var ul = tl.parent().find('ul:first');
            if (ul.children().length == 0)
            {
                ul.html("Loading...");
                tl.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
                var parent = tl.find('.tree-label').text(); alert(parent);
                $.post("<?php echo  Yii::$app->request->getbaseUrl(); ?>/index.php?r=accounts/stl_getchildren", {
                        parent: parent
                    },
                    function (data)
                    {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        var toolbar_g = '<span class="tree-node-toolbar"><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Add Child</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">View Ledger</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Rename</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item delete-btn">Delete</a></span>';
                        var toolbar_l = '<span class="tree-node-toolbar"><a class="tree-toolbar-item">View Ledger</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Rename</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item delete-btn">Delete</a></span>';
                        ul.html("");
```

when i run the code the error i get is  POST http://localhost/~user/church/backend/web/index.php?r=accounts/stl_getchildren 400 (Bad Request)  Undefined index: parent
when i alerted the var parent in view it shows the value but it is not  passing to the view. Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

error was due to csrfvalidation. i disabled it.
in view

```
 function loadChildren($this)
                {
                    var tl = $this;
                    tl.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-folder');
                    var ul = tl.parent().find('ul:first');
                    if (ul.children().length == 0)
                    {
                        ul.html("Loading...");
                        tl.find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-spinner fa-spin');
                        var parent = tl.find('.tree-label').text(); alert(parent);
                        $.post("<?php echo  Yii::$app->request->getbaseUrl(); ?>/index.php?r=accounts/stl_getchildren", {
                                parent: parent,
                                _csrf : csrfToken
                            },
                            function (data)
                            {
                                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                                var toolbar_g = '<span class="tree-node-toolbar"><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Add Child</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">View Ledger</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Rename</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item delete-btn">Delete</a></span>';
                                var toolbar_l = '<span class="tree-node-toolbar"><a class="tree-toolbar-item">View Ledger</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item">Rename</a><a class="tree-toolbar-item delete-btn">Delete</a></span>';
                                ul.html("");
```

in controller

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

now it is working perfectly. Sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 0):

You use `parent` both for value and for POST key but you have defined this like a var then the POST key don't contain the name `parent`. (parent undefined index)
Try  this way

```
            var parent_value = tl.find('.tree-label').text(); 
            alert(parent_value);
            $.post("<?php echo  Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/index.php?r=accounts/stl_getchildren", {
                    parent: parent_value
                }
```

and i usually use Yii::$app->request->baseUrl not the getBaseUrl() function

In controller try this way for $sql

```
$sql    = "SELECT parent.id AS account, ifnull( ABS( SUM(gle.debit)-SUM(gle.credit) ), 0 ) AS balance,
            parent.group_or_ledger, parent.lft 
            FROM tabAccount AS parent, tabAccount AS node
            LEFT JOIN `tabGLEntry` gle ON ( gle.account = node.id )
            WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) 
            AND parent.parent_account = " . $_POST['parent'] . "   
            AND parent.is_deleted=0
            GROUP BY parent.id
            ORDER BY parent.id";
```

Eventually try a var_dump( $_POST['parent']) or  var_dump( $_POST) for see the content. 
And Another tip use of $_POST is a bad pratice.. use load()...

Comment: I have update the answer with minro change 1)  alert in a proper row and not in the same row of the var. 2) use baseUrl instead of getBaseUrl().  If you want try it........

Comment: i did as u said, but i am  afraid i have the same error. thanks for the baseUrl tip.